# UIButton also highlighting when cell is touched

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uibutton

I've a `UIButton` on my table cell that pops up (`touchUpInside`) a `UIAlertView` and asks the user if they want to delete the file associated with that cell.  Otherwise, a touch on the cell itself highlights the cell then moves to the next level to reveal content.  The issue is that when the cell is `selected` and `highlighted`, the button highlights as well, confusing the user.

How can I tell the button to ignore touches to the cell or tell the cell to leave the damn button alone.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331967/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell , I think.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this workaround with mixed results. While it will return the `button` to its **`normal`** state, there is a brief flicker as it changes from normal, to `selected`, and back to normal again.

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CustomCell *cell = (CustomCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.button.highlighted = NO;
}
```