# Clarify undocumented behavior of UITableViewCell on highlight event

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

UITableViewCell modifies the contents of it's contentView hierarchy when the cell is is highlighted (user touches down on the cell).

Two examples I've found to date:

- Put a UIView in a cell's contentView with a background color. That UIView's background color is removed when the table cell is highlighted (it's apparently set to have a clear background.)
- Put a UIButton in contentView. When the cell is highlighted, the button is also forced into the highlighted state.

It's as if there's some logic in the UITableView cell that inspects all views in the cell's hierarchy and modifies them according to a set of mysterious rules, then restores them back to normal once the cell is un-highlighted.

Can anyone explain what and why UITableViewCell is modifying (unexpectedly and in an undocumented fashion) in the contents of my custom table view cells?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighting of the UITableViewCell is documented in the [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/highlighted) as follows:

> The highlighting affects the
>   appearance of labels, image, and
>   background. When the the highlighted
>   state of a cell is set to YES, labels
>   are drawn in their highlighted text
>   color (default is white). The default
>   value is is NO. If you set the
>   highlighted state to YES through this
>   property, the transition to the new
>   state appearance is not animated. For
>   animated highlighted-state
>   transitions, see the
>   setHighlighted:animated: method.
>
> Note that for highlighting to work
>   properly, you must fetch the cell’s
>   labels using the textLabel and
>   detailTextLabel properties and set
>   each label’s highlightedTextColor
>   property; for images, get the cell’s
>   image using the imageView property and
>   set the UIImageView object’s
>   highlightedImage property.

This does not mention UIButtons, but [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331967/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell) is about how to prevent the button from going into the highlighted state when the cell does.

Comment: Thank you though this is only partial documentation - it doesn't discuss how arbitrary UIView backgroundColor properties are also changed to clear, and so it's definitely an incomplete explanation. I'd like to get all the things it changes into the answer. However, the solution you link to - implementing custom highlight/selection states by overriding setHighlighted:animated: and setSelected:animated: - does allow me to completely prevent the mixed/undocumented highlight changes from happening, by not calling the super method in the overrides and doing everything myself.