# iOS Custom button in table cell gets dimmed when highlighted

Tags: ios, button, tableview, cell

I have a button added to a `UITableViewCell`, at the end. When highlighted, I have a custom highlight layer with transparency on the end. However, the button still gets dimmed, though it's still working. But the user can get the idea it has become inactive. I would like the button to stay as it is, even as the cell is highlighted. I would like to understand why and how the button gets dimmed, even if the highlight layer has full transparency there.

Comment: Have you set yourButton.isEnabled = FALSE ?

Comment: Not specifically. And the button is just functioning, that's not the issue. The thing is, it is dimmed when the table cell gets selected, even when the custom highlight layer has a transparency over there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769290/uibutton-also-highlighting-when-cell-is-touched

Comment: I suspect the button state to go to highlight when the cell is highlighted. I want the button to stay as it is.

Comment: cell.selectionStyle = NO leaves the button alone, but now the whole cell is not responding as one select it.

Answer (score 0):

[UIButton in UITableViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4331967/uibutton-in-uitableviewcell)

overriding some stuff to fix this.

I tried, but I don't know how to get 'yourButton' to be the button that is in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

This finds the button and sets its highlighted state to NO.

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
for(UIView *views in cell.subviews)
{
    if(views.tag == indexPath.row){
        for(UIButton *deKnop in views.subviews)
        {
            deKnop.highlighted = NO;
        }
    }
    //if ( [views isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]] ) {
        //do your code
        //[subviews setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PENCIL.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    //}
}
```

Comment: In the simulator I can hardly discover any flickering, but I guess there technically is.